# moving back to web pages after logout is callled

Tags: django

In login, the key to the department is stored in secession and is redirected to the desired department of the user

*in login_validation*

```
  check = models.user.authenticate(password_entered, username_entered)

        if check:
            print('valid login')
            # check the type of user
            request.session['department'] = check['department']             
            request.session.modified = True
```

and at logout the the department key is deleted

```
def logout(request):
    if request.session.has_key('department'):
        del request.session['department']
        request.session.modified = True
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'login_form': forms.login_form})
```

and each page inside the website is checked if department key present if not the user is redirected to the login page

```
def parts_home(request):
    try:
        department= request.session['department']
        if department != 'parts':
            raise Exception
    except:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:login_page'))
```

this works fine while hard-coding the URL of the department in the address bar but after pressing back button after logout is called the department key is not checked and the department page is loaded instead of login page. what is the solution?

Comment: try adding `if not request.user.is_authenticated():return 
 HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:login_page'))`  at the first line inside your logout view and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try decorator `login_required`

Add this decorator before your view function.

For example,

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/login')
def my_view(request):
    ....
    ....
```

Reference:
[the-login-required-decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator)